# Are there hooks in ASP.NET MVC prior to layout execution and post body render?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When ASP.NET MVC executes a page containing Razor it will first run the body eg the `RenderBody` method then it runs the code for the layout and weaves it together.

This is documented in this [blog post](http://yingbiao.blogspot.com.au/2010/12/dive-deep-into-aspnet-mvc-razor-view.html):

> System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView() 
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() //non virtual
>   version   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PushContext()
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() //virtual
>   version    this.Execute()  //Generated code from our View
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext
>   RenderSurrounding(virtualPath, body); //Render Layout, which is
>   similar to View's rendering process, essentially you can have nested
>   Layout    VerifyRenderdBodyOrSetions();

I want to add code to my views and layout that traces the *actual* logical position in the page.

Is there a way I can hook up a method to run **just before** RenderSurrounding and **just after** `RenderBody` finishes executing?

Comment: `RenderBody` is invoked by the layout (at least in the couple MVC projects I've worked on). You could possibly wrap `RenderSurrounding` in a helper (it if isn't already one) and add it before and after the call to `RenderBody` in the layout.

Comment: @M.Babcock ideally I am looking for a hook in the framework that involves no layout changes

Comment: But your question says: *I want to add code to my views and layout that traces the actual logical position in the page.* So aren't you looking to change the layout anyway?

Comment: @M.Babcock doing a poor job explaining myself see: http://snipt.org/uNq8 I want to automatically hook up MarkLayoutStart and MarkLayoutBodyRendered without editing my master layout

Comment: Have you thought about just writing your own base page that inherits from `RazorView`? See http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx

Comment: Another option may be to customize [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) to generate instrumented binary views.

Comment: Oops, mean inherits from [`WebPageBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase(v=vs.99).aspx)

Comment: I just checked MVC4 to see if any of these methods were made virtual, no luck...

Answer (score 8):

You can override the `ExecutePageHierarchy` method on the page itself by creating a different base type for your pages, given a `WebViewPage` implementation like this:

```
public abstract class CustomViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public override void ExecutePageHierarchy()
    {
        Output.Write("Before");
        base.ExecutePageHierarchy();
        Output.Write("After");
    }
}
```

You will get output just before and after the actual page's content (and thus inside the layout).  I'm not sure if thats what you are looking for, are you trying to just write the scripts at `</body>` I imagine?

The main thing is to use this kind of a base type for just the main .cshtml (not any partials or on the layout) it will render those `Output.Write`s around the `RenderBody` output of the layout (well really, just inside).

You can set the base type per directory in the `web.config`.